# What tax forms should I file for my new, 2016 LLC?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, limited-liability-company, california, s-corporation

I'm the only member (owner).

2016 is the first year (year of incorporation).

There were expenses (~$16k) but no income.

My plan is to file the 568 by March 15th but not file any federal corporate form, and flow the $16k loss through to schedule-C of my 1040.

Is this what the IRS and the California Fran Tax Board want?